# Variável global não muda o valor

Tags: python, variáveis, variáveis-globais

Eu sou um iniciante e não sei porque esse código não funciona.
Alguém pode me dizer porquê?

```
def teste():    
    global res1
    res1 = input().strip()

if res1 == '1':
    print('funciona')
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

O maior motivo é que você declarou a função mas não a chamou, então ela não é executada e nada acontece. Assim funciona:

```
def teste():    
    global res1
    res1 = input().strip()
 
teste()
if res1 == '1':
    print('funciona')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cfJ8EF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ezshvqbg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/InputFunction.py).

Não garanto que a entrada de dados possa estar causando algum outro problema também.

Mas vou te dar algumas dicas para produzir códigos melhores.

A primeira dica é não usar `global` até dominar todo o resto da programação e estruturas de Python. Isso é problemático e útil em raros casos. Precisa de bastante experiência para fazer certo. Funciona nesse caso simples, mas vai te ensinar errado. Aprenda usar funções do jeito correto, passando argumentos e recebendo dados como retorno.

Dê nomes significativos para funções e variáveis, assim o código fica mais explicativo.

Só use uma função se ela for realmente necessária. Em um código assim não é. Se quer aprender usar função procure um problema que precise de uma função. Não que não possa usar, mas de qualquer forma se é para usar então use do jeito certo.

Para um primeiro exemplo pode até fazer simples, mas qualquer dados digitado deveria ser validado. E não sei para que esse `strip()`, ele só complica o que está fazendo e não parece ter muito motivo. Se tiver algum motivo, tente fazer de outra forma, isso tem mais chance de dar errado. Não estou falando para validar agora, até porque não causará um problema tão grande, mas em casos reais precisará fazer isso. E justamente por ser simples demais não faz sentido esse `strip()`.

Assim fica melhor, embora não perfeito:

```
def pede_dados():    
    return input()
 
if pede_dados() == '1':
    print('funciona')
```

Melhor ainda:

```
if input() == '1':
    print('funciona')
```